# 交通アクセスの情報から徒歩分数の数値のみを取り出す方法

Tags: python, 正規表現

ホテルのアクセス状況にある、最寄り駅からの「徒歩分数」から、徒歩分数の数値を取得したいと考えています。
徒歩分数の数値のみを取り出して、それ以外は欠損値とする、
新たなデータを作成したいと考えています。

```
import re
import pandas as pd
import zenhan　# 全角半角を修正するモジュール

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'x': ['交通アクセスJR神田駅より徒歩４分', 
           '交通アクセス東京駅1駅2分、東京ディズニーリゾート(R)2駅12分◆八丁堀駅A2・A3出口から徒歩3分◆銀座・有楽町へアクセス良好！', 
           '交通アクセス東京駅より徒歩３分（八重洲中央口より）、羽田空港よりリムジンバスで30分、成田空港よりJRエクスプレスで60分。', 
           'アクセス：JR東京駅から3駅7分「潮見駅」（東口）からすぐ右手正面TDR・TDL「JR舞浜」まで3駅8分駐車場：敷地内45台1泊1,500円先着順予約不可駐車台数に限りがある為、極力公共交通機関をご利用下さい', 
           'アクセス：ＪＲ神田駅・営団地下鉄銀座線神田駅徒歩２分駐車場：なし']})

def get_walk_time(s):
    s = zenhan.z2h(s)
    if not re.match(r'(徒歩|約)', s):
        return None
    m = re.search(r'(\d+)分', s)
    return m.group(1)

df["walk_time"] = df.x.map(get_walk_time)
print(df.walk_time)
```

現在は次のような結果になっています。

0    None
1    None
2    None
3    None
4    None

次のようなデータを作成したいと考えています。
0    4
1    3
2    3
3    None
4    2

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`re.match`は文字列の先頭がパターンにマッチするかどうかなのですべて`None`になります。次のように修正したらどうでしょうか。

```
def get_walk_time(s):
    m = re.search(r'(徒歩|約)(\d+)分', s)
    return zenhan.z2h(m.group(2)) if m else None
```

なお、Python3では、`\d`は全角の数値にもマッチするので上のように変更してみました。他との互換性を考えると`zenhan.z2h()`で半角に変換後でもいいと思います。

コメントを参考にすると以下のように簡単になります。数字が`float`、`None`が`numpy.nan`になりますがこちらを使うほうが通常は便利です。

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'x': ['交通アクセスJR神田駅より徒歩４分', 
           '交通アクセス東京駅1駅2分、東京ディズニーリゾート(R)2駅12分◆八丁堀駅A2・A3出口から徒歩3分◆銀座・有楽町へアクセス良好！', 
           '交通アクセス東京駅より徒歩３分（八重洲中央口より）、羽田空港よりリムジンバスで30分、成田空港よりJRエクスプレスで60分。', 
           'アクセス：JR東京駅から3駅7分「潮見駅」（東口）からすぐ右手正面TDR・TDL「JR舞浜」まで3駅8分駐車場：敷地内45台1泊1,500円先着順予約不可駐車台数に限りがある為、極力公共交通機関をご利用下さい', 
           'アクセス：ＪＲ神田駅・営団地下鉄銀座線神田駅徒歩２分駐車場：なし']})

df["walk_time"] = df.x.str.extract('(徒歩|約)(\d+)分')[1].astype(float)
print(df.walk_time)
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。詳しい解説も載せて頂き、大変助かります。早速、修正させていただきます。

Comment: @kazusumi 結果をint型、欠損値をNoneにしたい場合は、`df.x.str.extract('(徒歩|約)(\d+)分', expand=False)[1].fillna(-1).astype(int).replace({-1: None})` としてもよろしいかと。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。いろいろなやり方があることが分かります。